# time.sleep gets executed in wrong order

Tags: python, tkinter

I am coding a TicTacToe game at the moment and I tried to "lock" a field after a player placed a cross or a circle in it so that you can't change it afterwards.
So i tried to do it like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

#---------------------------------------Definitions-------------------------------------------------
def startgame():
    global whois
    whois = 1
    turn.place(x=413, y=150)
    Player1.place(x=10, y=5)
    Player2.place(x=10, y=45)
    PlayerCross.place(x=150, y=52)
    PlayerCircle.place(x=150, y=10)
    A1.place(x=158, y=204, width=223, height=228)
    A2.place(x=387, y=204, width=232, height=228)
    A3.place(x=626, y=204, width=225, height=228)
    B1.place(x=158, y=438, width=223, height=231)
    B2.place(x=387, y=438, width=232, height=231)
    B3.place(x=626, y=438, width=225, height=231)
    C1.place(x=158, y=675, width=223, height=226)
    C2.place(x=387, y=675, width=232, height=226)
    C3.place(x=626, y=675, width=225, height=226)
    startscreen.place_forget()
    start.place_forget()
    turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"

#-----------------HERE IS MY PROBLEM--------------------------------------------

def turnimage(a):
    global whois
    if whois == 1 and a["image"] == str(standartTexture):
        turn["text"] = "Player 2's turn!"
        a["image"] = circle
        whois = 2
    elif whois == 2 and a["image"] == str(standartTexture):
        turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
        a["image"] = cross
        whois = 1
    else:
        error.place(x = 330, y = 920)
        time.sleep(1)
        error.place_forget()

#-----------------------------------------------------------



#---------------------------------------------variables-------------------------------------------------------

background = tk.PhotoImage(file = "TicTacToe_bg.png")
standartTexture = tk.PhotoImage(file = "standartTexture.png")
cross = tk.PhotoImage(file = "cross.png")
circle = tk.PhotoImage(file = "circle.png")
PlayerCrossImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCross.png")
PlayerCircleImage = tk.PhotoImage(file = "PlayerCircle.png")


whois = 0
field = tk.Label(root, image = background)
turn = tk.Label(root, text = " ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player1 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 1 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
Player2 = tk.Label(root, text = "Player 2 = ", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", font = "Ariel 20")
PlayerCross = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCrossImage, bd = 0)
PlayerCircle = tk.Label(root, image = PlayerCircleImage, bd = 0)
startscreen = tk.Label(root, text = "", height = 500, width = 500, bg = "#FFFFFF")
start = tk.Button(root, text = "Start", font = "Ariel 50", bg = "#FFFFFF", fg = "#000000", command = startgame)
error = tk.Label(root, text = "This field is already occupied!", font = "Ariel 20", bg = "#FFFFFF")

A1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A1))
A2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A2))
A3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(A3))
B1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B1))
B2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B2))
B3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(B3))
C1 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C1))
C2 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C2))
C3 = tk.Button(root, image = standartTexture, bd = 0, command = lambda: turnimage(C3))
#--------------------------------------------place stuff-----------------------------------------------------------------

startscreen.place(x = 148, y = 195)
field.pack()
start.place(x = 400, y = 400)

root.mainloop()
```

But when I run it the label gets placed after one second and than dissapears immediately so you can't even see it.

Comment: While the code is sleeping it can't update the screen. As a general rule of thumb you should never call sleep in the main thread of a GUI.

Comment: So what should i do instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent modification of a button, set its `state` to `DISABLED`, e.g:

```
A1["state"] = tk.DISABLED
```

Note that you should *not* use `time.sleep()` in a GUI program. It will halt the processing of events, rendering the GUI unrespronsive.

So you can change `turnimage` into:

```
def turnimage(a):
    global whois
    if whois == 1:
        turn["text"] = "Player 2's turn!"
        a["image"] = circle
        whois = 2
    else:
        turn["text"] = "Player 1's turn!"
        a["image"] = cross
        whois = 1
    # This should happen in both cases, 
    # so put it after the if-statement.
    a["state"] = tk.DISABLED
```

Note that:

- It is not necessary to test whether a button contains an image. After an image is set, it is disabled.
- If you don't want to disable a button (because that changes the appearance), you could achieve more or less the same by setting `a["command"] = None`, making it unresponsive to clicks.

Comment: So how should i do this in my code because i don't know exactly what you mean

Comment: @Toschi-07 See updated answer.